# How to make MediaElementPlayer start when scrolled into view?

Tags: javascript, html, video

So I was wondering if I could make it so that the video on my website starts playing when the user scrolls into the view of it. 
I've tried quite a few things such as scrollspy and some other code I found on this website, but none of it works, I always get the same result: the website messes up completely, pictures move out of sight, sections change places or disappear and it's not very fun.

This is the current JS code for our MediaElementPlayer:

```
if ($('.video-promo').length ) {
    var player_promo = new MediaElementPlayer('.video-promo', {
        videoWidth: '100%',
        videoHeight: '100%',
        loop: false,
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: [],
    });

    player_promo.play();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
        <section class="promo motions">
        <video class="video-promo">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/video/demo.mp4" />
        </video>
      <div class="video-overlay"></div>
    </section>
```

Cheers for any help! :D

Comment: could you please post some fiddle to help you quicker?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Dan's answer on:
[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

In short you can add:

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}

function elementVisibilityMayChange () {
    return function () {
        if ( isElementInViewport($('.video-promo')[0]) ) {
            player_promo.play();
        }
    }
}

var handler = elementVisibilityMayChange();

$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', handler);
```

Comment: Cheers! Where should I add this?

Comment: Anywhere on the page with the video player would do.

Comment: I did exactly that, but it still messed up the page.  
Example: http://i.imgur.com/dDdMIjz.png & http://i.imgur.com/xkpRB5M.png (that's the video - it usually takes up that whole area.  
I'd show more, but I don't really want to show too much of my unfinished website :3

Comment: Alright, so I got it to stop messing up the page, but it still doesn't play the video when I scroll onto it.